# getting java.lang.VerifyError in android, advertising Id function

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the advertising Id from an android device. In my code, I am following the google's doc(https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html) and using:

```
public void a(Context mContext) {
    adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(mContext);
}
```

then in Activity I am writing below code:

```
public class XXActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    A a = new A(this);
}
```

However when I trigger this activity, I got a 'java.lang.VerifyError' error. Can anyone give me a help? Thanks!

**Error log:**

```
02-24 16:18:32.984: D/gralloc_goldfish(803): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-24 16:18:36.005: I/dalvikvm(803): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo, referenced from method com.mypackage.customevent.CustomEvent.setUpGlobal
02-24 16:18:36.005: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5577: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;.getAdvertisingIdInfo (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
02-24 16:18:36.014: D/dalvikvm(803): VFY: replacing opcode 0x77 at 0x0042
02-24 16:18:36.014: I/dalvikvm(803): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info.getId, referenced from method com.mypackage.customevent.CustomEvent.setUpGlobal
02-24 16:18:36.014: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5576: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;.getId ()Ljava/lang/String;
02-24 16:18:36.014: D/dalvikvm(803): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0046
02-24 16:18:36.014: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 808 (Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;)
02-24 16:18:36.024: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x263
02-24 16:18:36.024: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mypackage/customevent/CustomEvent;.setUpGlobal ()Lcom/mypackage/customevent/GlobalProperties;
02-24 16:18:36.024: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0263
02-24 16:18:36.024: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mypackage/customevent/CustomEvent;.setUpGlobal ()Lcom/mypackage/customevent/GlobalProperties;
02-24 16:18:36.024: W/dalvikvm(803): Verifier rejected class Lcom/mypackage/customevent/CustomEvent;
02-24 16:18:36.024: D/AndroidRuntime(803): Shutting down VM
02-24 16:18:36.024: W/dalvikvm(803): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
02-24 16:18:36.024: E/ACRA(803): ACRA caught a VerifyError exception for com.package.jokeapp. Building report.
```

And this is what I defined in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you show the output from logcat?  There should be a few lines above the exception that provide details about the problem.

Comment: could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.advertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo, referrerced from method ...                                    unable to resolve static method 4069: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;

Comment: Copy & paste it into the question.  If there are any lines with `VFY` make sure to include those.

Comment: Looks like you're missing multiple items from com.google.android.gms.  Something not linked in?

Comment: Hi @fadden, so you think the problem is coming from maven dependency?